# Беспорядок в метке [inline]

Tags: обсуждение, метки

В метке [inline](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) есть вопросы, связанные с:

- Встраиваемыми функциями (англ. «*inline functions*») в языках
  типа *C* и *C++*.
- *JavaScript* внутри *(X)HTML*.
- Отображением блоков в *CSS* (`display: inline`
  и `display: inline-block`).
- Ботами в *Telegram*.
- Какими-то случайностями.

Честно говоря, не знаю, что с этой меткой вообще делать.  Мне
кажется, что её следует оставить только для первого использования,
а остальное вычистить, но «*inline
functions*» — это по-русски «встраиваемые
функции», так что возможно стоит создать такую метку и сделать метку
[inline](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) её синонимом.

Что скажет сообщество?

Comment: То значение, которое используется чаще всего в вопросах с этой меткой, добавить в её описание. С оставшихся вопросов убрать. Так меньше всего править надо

Comment: По-моему такую расплывчатую метку нужно убрать: нет такой области в программировании, как "inline". Нельзя быть специалистом по инлайнам, ведь от контекста к контексту значение данного слова меняется. Делаем вывод: метка не нужна (причина: слишком расплывчатая и контекстозависимая).

Comment: Думаю, не стоит так переименовывать вопрос, люди же плюсы ставили под изначальный вопрос. Лучше дать ответ с предложением удаления

Comment: Можно написать несколько ответов и смотреть по голосам на них.

Comment: @Ainar-G ну да, я про это и говорю. А вы изменили изначальный вопрос и теперь кажется, будто 9 человек проголосовало за удаление. Откатите назад и дайте эти несколько ответов

Comment: @Ainar-G лучше откатить к изначальной версии и провести голосование)

Comment: @dim0n, Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik  Сделано.

Answer (score 2):

> По-моему такую расплывчатую метку нужно убрать: нет такой области в программировании, как "inline". Нельзя быть специалистом по инлайнам, ведь от контекста к контексту значение данного слова меняется. Делаем вывод: метка не нужна (причина: слишком расплывчатая и контекстозависимая).

– return

Comment: Эээ... Это что? Общее сообщение, в котором... содержится комментарий конкретного пользователя.... Это зачем так?

Comment: @Зонтик чтобы можно было устроить некое подобие голосования.

Answer (score 1):

#### **Откуда эта метка взялась?**

У этой метки нет описания, а термин "inline" встречается во многих языках и технологиях, поэтому каждый участник, использующий метку, по-своему интерпретировал смысл метки. Вот и получился беспорядок.

#### Что с ней делать?

В данном случае метка действительно смысла не имеет. Дело в том, что темы, с которыми связаны вопросы случайны и очень сильно разнятся. Я думаю, что эту метку стоит разбить на несколько других (автор вопроса написал список тем, с которыми связаны вопросы в этой метке, вот по этому списку и разбить):

> Автор вопроса:
> В метке inline есть вопросы, связанные с:
>
> 1. Встраиваемыми функциями (англ. «inline functions») в языках типа C и C++.
> 2. JavaScript внутри (X)HTML.
> 3. Отображением блоков в CSS (display: inline и display: inline-block).
> 4. Ботами в Telegram.

#### Как не допускать появления таких меток в будующем?

Нужно добавлять метками описание, желательно сразу после создания метки, тогда такого беспорядка не будет (см. причины появления)